# android listview retain last viewed list item view before recycling

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I'm using a list view, and I'm using the View holder pattern and recycling views. All working great and as expected. The list scroll smoothly and I'm quite happy with the implementation, besides one thing.

I would like to retain the last 3 views that were scroll off the screen before I get their views to recycle. I would like to do that in order to achieve the following. I have images in my list and I'm loading them asynchronously and they have some fade in animation. It all good as long the user scroll to new items, but I would like that in case that the user scroll back again, that the images would be populated already and won't be loaded again. Of course that I don't want all the previous view to save, but the last few items (lets say three) is reasonable.

Any thoughts on how to achieve it?

Thanks

**--EDIT--**

To answer some comments. The fade in effect has no influence on the problem (it just more easy to identify it) without the fade in, the image just appear, but the user would see the place holder of the photo (it takes few milliseconds, and it is depends on the current state of the OS).

To solve the problem there should be some caching mechanism to the list view that hold the last X elements that were seen by the user and scrolled off already, and when the user scroll back to those elements the list view should send the convertView of the cached view it saved.

I managed to do that artificially for one element, just to test the concept, and it worked fine. But I have reason to assume that some kind of caching mechanism of elements in a list view it is something that probably implemented already in the ListView itself, or someone already implemented something like that already.

You can think of it as follow. Now the ListView holds the number of elements seen on the screen and the last one that was seen and when there is a need to draw the next element the list view sends the last seen element as the convert view. The solution means that the list view would hold the seen elements + the X elements of the caching and the last element that was scroll off and is not in the caching anymore. When a new element should be drawn the list view will give it the element that is shouldn't be cached anymore, unless the user scroll back to an element that exist in the caching, then the element from the caching would be sent as the convert view

**--Edit 2--**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {       
        //Get the item
        final ItemForListActivity item = itemsListHashtable.get(position);

        ViewGroup rowLayout;
        //In case that the view is new create it
        if (item.getItemType() == Interface.LIST_ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT)
        {
            ListItemViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                rowLayout = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ListItemViewHolder();
                viewHolder.image1 = (ImageView) rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.image1);
                viewHolder.image2 = (ImageView) rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.image2);
                //We save the item id that is associate with the holder, for now nothing is associate with it. 
                viewHolder.itemId = -1;
                rowLayout.setTag(viewHolder);
            }           
            //Otherwise just use the converted view
            else 
            {
                rowLayout = (ViewGroup) convertView;
                viewHolder = (ListItemViewHolder) rowLayout.getTag();
            }

                //Only in case that the item id is not the one that is already drawn, we need to draw the item 
                if (viewHolder.itemId != item.getItemId())
                {
                    viewHolder.itemId = item.getItemId();

                    //Draw image1
                    drawImage1(viewHolder, item);
                    //Draw image2
                    drawImage2(viewHolder, item);
                }
         }


        return rowLayout;
    }
```

Comment: which library are you using todisplay your images?

Comment: @LenaBru I'm not sure I understood the question. The images are stored on the sandbox memory of the app. And I wrote my own code to scale them down and populate them on the list in a background thread.

Comment: can you post some code?
what happens if you disable the fadein effect?

Comment: Please see my update, I hope it clarify my issue better. I didn't upload code, since the question is regarding the base mechanism of the ListView, and the code that handle this list view is spanned over few objects, and it would just make things more cumbersome.

Comment: can you post your getView method please ?

Comment: I added the code. The draw image function, download the image if it is not exist, and populate the image to the list item in case that the scroll is slow enough. all is being done in a background thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54384/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-nheimann1).